# Importance of knowing if a standard library function is executing a system call

Tags: system-calls

Is it actually important for a programmer to know if the standard library function he/she is using is actually executing a system call? If so, why?

Intuitively I'm guessing the only importance is in knowing if the general standard function is a library function or a system call itself. In other cases, I'm guessing there isn't much of a need to know if a library functions uses internally a system call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always possible to know (for sure) if a library function wraps a system call. But in one way or another, this knowledge can help improve the portability and (or) efficiency of your program. At least in the following two cases, knowing the syscall-level behaviours of your program is helpful.

1. When your program is time critical. Some system calls are expensive, and the library functions that wrap them are even more expensive. Thus time-critical tasks may need to switch to equivalent functions that do not enter kernel space at all.

   It is also worth noticing the `vsyscall` (or `vdso`) mechanism of linux, which accelerates some system calls (i.e. `gettimeofday`) through mapping their implementations into user-space memory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266813/anyone-can-understand-how-gettimeofday-works) for more details.
2. When your program needs to be deployed to some restricted environments with system call auditing. In order for your programs to survive such environments, it could be necessary to profile your program for any potential policy violations, or perhaps less tough if you are aware of the restrictions when you wrote the program.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it might be important, and sometimes it isn't. I don't think there's any universal answer to this question. Reasons I can think of that *might* be important in *some* contexts are: if the system call requires user permissions that the user might not have; in performance critical code a system call might be too heavyweight; if you're writing a signal-handler where most system calls are forbidden; if it might use some system resource (e.g. reading from /dev/random for every random number could use up the whole entropy pool - you'd want to know if that's going to happen every time you call `rand()`).