# difference between time() and gettimeofday() and why does one cause seg fault

Tags: c, linux, time, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to measure the amount of time for a system call, and I tried using `time(0)` and `gettimeofday()` in this program, but whenever I use `gettimeofday()` it seg faults. I suppose I can just use `time(0)` but I'd like to know why this is happening. And I know you guys can just look at it and see the problem. Please don't yell at me!

I want to get the time but not save it anywhere.

I've tried every combination of code I can think of but I pasted the simplest version here. I'm new to C and Linux. I look at the .stackdump file but it's pretty meaningless to me.

GetRDTSC is in util.h and it does `rdtsc()`, as one might expect. Now it's set to 10 iterations but later the loop will run 1000 times, without `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "util.h"

int main() {

    int i;
    uint64_t cycles[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

         // get initial cycles
         uint64_t init = GetRDTSC();

         gettimeofday(); // <== time(0) will work here without a seg fault.

         // get cycles after
         uint64_t after = GetRDTSC();   

         // save cycles for each operation in an array
         cycles[i] = after - init;

         printf("%i\n", (int)(cycles[i]));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Just trying to understand how you can compile this code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The short version

`gettimeofday()` requires a pointer to a `struct timeval` to fill with time data.

So, for example, you'd do something like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {  
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); // timezone should be NULL
    printf("%d seconds\n", tv.tv_secs);
    return 0;
}
```

### The long version

The *real* problem is that gcc is automatically including `vdso` on your system, which contains a symbol for the syscall `gettimeofday`. Consider this program (entire file):

```
int main() {
  gettimeofday();
  return 0;
}
```

By default, gcc will compile this *without warning*. If you check the symbols it's linked against, you'll see:

```
ternus@event-horizon ~> gcc -o foo foo.c
ternus@event-horizon ~> ldd foo
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff33fe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f56a5255000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f56a562b000)
```

You just happen to be using a function that has a defined symbol, but without the prototype, there's no way to tell how many command-line arguments it's supposed to have.

If you compile it with `-Wall`, you'll see:

```
ternus@event-horizon ~> gcc -Wall -o foo foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:2:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettimeofday’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Of course, it'll segfault when you try to run it. Interestingly, it'll segfault in kernel space (this is on MacOS):

```
cternus@astarael ~/foo> gcc -o foo -g foo.c
cternus@astarael ~/foo> gdb foo
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
[etc]

(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/cternus/foo/foo
Reading symbols for shared libraries +.............................. done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000001
0x00007fff87eeab73 in __commpage_gettimeofday ()
```

Now consider this program (again, no header files):

```
typedef struct {
  long tv_sec;
  long tv_usec;
} timeval;

int main() {
  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

This will compile and run just fine -- no segfault. You've provided it with the memory location it expects, even though there's still no `gettimeofday` prototype provided.

More information:

[Can anyone understand how gettimeofday works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266813/anyone-can-understand-how-gettimeofday-works)

[Is there a faster equivalent of gettimeofday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498972/faster-equivalent-of-gettimeofday)

[The POSIX gettimeofday specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html)

Comment: It actually takes two arguments: timeval and timezone

Comment: Right. "The use of the timezone structure is obsolete; the tz argument should normally be specified as NULL." http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a wrong-number-of-args error, not a seg fault? Since I don't want to save the time I tried using gettimeofday(0,0) and it gave the same result as gettimeofday(). Will adding &tv add cycles to the operation?

Comment: @punstress: It would if you used the right compiler options (`-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`). Complain to the gcc developers that this option is still not default (this should always be an error, not a warning; it's invalid C and very dangerous).

Comment: I think you also need to `#include <sys/time.h>`, right now the compiler assumes `gettimeofday` is a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`, which is why it didn't complain, use `-Wall` to make it complain (for your own good).

Comment: kninnug interesting idea, i had sys/time.h before and chgd it, so I tried changing it back just now and it failed seg fault. oh well i gtg so i'll look at this later.

Comment: Would it matter if i added that i'm using cygwin not real linux?

Comment: Performance-wise? Maybe. Implementation-wise? Nope. ["Cygwin consists of a library that implements the POSIX system call API in terms of Win32 system calls."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)