# Where is the Linux ISR Entry Point

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to understand the system call interface and implementation in the Linux kernel. I know about `entry.S` and the relationship between `libc` headers and implementation. What I want to know is where in the kernel is the `int 80h` received for the first time i.e. the place that decides that it's actually the 80h interrupt. Can anyone point me to the LXR link for this please?

Comment: Will [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499188/how-is-the-system-call-in-linux-implemented) help?

Comment: Hnn. It does help actually. It appears that 0x80 is no longer used. It's now a SYSENTER/SYSEXIT based approach which is explained very nice here: http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONFIG_X86_32`

1. [arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S:system_call](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L499) (INT $0x80)
2. [arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S:ia32_sysenter_target](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L376) (SYSENTER)

`CONFIG_X86_64`

1. [arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S:system_call](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L456) (SYSCALL, 64bit)

`CONFIG_X86_64 and CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`

1. [arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S:ia32_sysenter_target](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S#L117) (SYSENTER)
2. [arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S:ia32_cstar_target](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S#L277) (SYSCALL, 32bit)
3. [arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S:ia32_syscall](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.5/arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S#L401) (INT $0x80)